# IndexOutOfBoundsException when using an enhanced for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

My enhanced for-loop returns an IndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to run this:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> multipliser(ArrayList<Double> listen, int multi) {

    for(double elementer : listen) {
        listen.set((int) elementer, listen.get((int) elementer * multi)); 
    }
    return listen;
```

It works flawlessly with an good old for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listen.size(); i++) {
    listen.set(i, listen.get(i) * multi);
}
return listen;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "What am I missing?" A [mcve]; the stack trace.

Comment: In particular, you're using the *values* in the list as *indexes* in the first version, but not the second. In other words, they're completely different.

Comment: @AndyTurner, thank you very much for that link, I strive for perfection :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
listen.get((int) elementer * multi)
```

is not the same as

```
listen.get(i)*multi
```

Similarly in the `set`.

But an easier way to multiply everything in the list by a constant in-place (in Java 8+) is:

```
listen.replaceAll(x -> x * multi);
```

The easiest way pre-Java 8 is to use a `ListIterator`:

```
for (ListIterator<Double> it = listen.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  it.set(it.next() * multi);
}
```

(Note that this is roughly how the default implementation of `Collection.replaceAll` looks in Java 8+).

Answer (score 1):

In your "enhanced for" loop you're setting your elements at the index corresponding to their value instead of the index of the current loop iteration.

Generally speaking I would discourage you to edit a list you're looping on or an object that was passed as an argument. You should create a new list to return instead:

```
List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (double elementer : listen) {
    result.add(elementer * multi);
}
return result;
```

Also use interfaces ([`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)) in method signatures, not implementations ([`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)):

```
public static List<Double> multipliser(List<Double> listen, int multi) {
```

---

You can even try this instead which is smaller and so 2017+ (Java 8+):

```
return listen.stream().map(x -> x * multi).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or even [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) as [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48585954/1771634) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much! I understand now how I was erroneously using the elements and not the index. The code that works (far from optimal) looks like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> multipliser(ArrayList<Double> listen, int multi){
    int i = 0; 
    for(double elementer : listen) {
        listen.set(i, elementer*multi);
        i++;
    }
    return listen;
```

Thanks everyone and have a great weekend!